# PIL / Python 3 Porting Impressive

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to port [Impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net) to use it with python3.

At some point there the LOGO has to be loaded. The LOGO is hard coded.
So it would look something like this:

```
LOGO = '\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x0 ...'
LogoImage = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(LOGO))
```

When trying to port this to use with python3 by changing the line to:

```
LogoImage = Image.open(io.StringIO(LOGO))
```

I get the following Error Message

```
OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.StringIO object at 0x106b388b8>
```

I read a bit about StringIO und BytesIO. Wasn't able to find a solution yet though.

Edit:

Loading images from disc is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`bytes` instead of `str`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings), [`io.Bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) instead of [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO):

```
LOGO = b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x0 ...'   # NOTE: leading `b`
LogoImage = Image.open(io.BytesIO(LOGO))
```

Comment: Well, I did try to use BytesIO already. The image is hardcoded though so the first error message that will pop will be: 'TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface'. When trying to use bytes(LOGO, 'UTF-8'). It will again be an Error Message like: 'cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO ...' just that StringIO was replaced with BytesIO.

Comment: @Nimi, Try `latin1` encoding. `bytes(LOGO, 'latin1')` or `LOGO.encode('latin1')`

Comment: It was the comment that helped though. :P